# (Maple) Finding the number of terms of the 2014th Term of Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: calculus, maple

The Fibonacci sequence is defined by F0 = F1 = 1 and Fn = Fn−2 + Fn−1, n ≥ 2.
In Maple, we can define the Fibonacci sequence as procedure:

> F:=proc(n::nonnegint) option remember;
>
> if n<2 then 1 else F(n-2)+F(n-1) end if;
>
> end proc;

Consider the sequence defined by H0 = 0, H1 = 1, H2 = 2, and

Hn = (n − 3)Hn−3 + (n − 2)Hn−2 + (n − 1)Hn−1, n ≥ 3.
How many digits does H2014 have?

**Is there a command to find the number of digits a term have?**

Comment: Try to take the log base 10.

Comment: Or print it to a string and count the number of characters.

Comment: BTW, that method for computing the Fibs is incredibly inefficient. If done naively, it will take about $2^n$ operations. It is *far* better to have the standard loop which remembers the last two values.

Comment: How do you go about doing this? As we are taught really limited functions on maple. So sorry for the trouble

Comment: Not true, @marty cohen. Note that the code specifies **option remember**. So Maple automatically does the remembering that you suggest.

Comment: Not to worry, @Zenno. Your use of **option remember** is perfectly correct.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. My ignorance has been reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maple command that you need is **ilog10**. The number of decimal digits of a positive integer **n** is **1+ilog10(n)**. The answer is 5782 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits of an integer $n$ is exactly the largest integer less than or equal to $\log_{10}(n)$